# What problems arise from mixing HTTP and HTTPS content through iframes?

Tags: http, iframe, web, https, cross-browser

If I use HTTP images or JS content within an HTTPS iframe (`//`) within that HTTPS site, is there a problem?

```
Site: HTTPS
iframe within site: HTTPS
image content within iframe within site: HTTP
```

What happens to the browser (safari, explorer, chrome, ios safari ...., ) in this case?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOwJG.png)

**Above is an image of the current situation.
To help you understand better**

**I thought it was going to be a problem.
There are no problems with the current site and no web browser errors.
It is very strange.**

Comment: Everything should be HTTPS, including iFrames and third-party libraries. See https://doesmysiteneedhttps.com.

Comment: Your post is barely unreadable, please edit it adding relevant information and formatting text/code.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, at least in Chrome, it will refuse to download HTTP resource on an HTTPS page and log it to console.